# CodeIgniter deleting index.php with htaccess after normal installation of apache 2.4

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have installed PHP, Mysql and Apache on windows server 2008 R2 as [this link](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/) provided exactly.

It's working like a charm, but the problem is with my `.htaccess` to remove `index.php`.

My `.htaccess` file includes the following:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /HR/    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I already enabled `mod_rewrite` in apache. but I'm getting 500 internal server error.

**NOTE:** when changing `AllowOverRide All` to `None` in Document root like here:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
```

the `500 internal error` disappears but the `.htaccess` does not work!!! then I should add the `index.php` for the link to work.

Note: when `AllowIverRide All` I get this error:

```
[Tue Feb 19 18:20:10.988018 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3940:tid 844] 
[client 127.0.0.1:49513] C:/Apache24/htdocs/HR/.htaccess: 
RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
```

Any help will be Appreciated. TY.

Comment: Did you edit config.php and change config['index_page'] to equal ""? If that still says "index.php" that may be your issue.

Comment: What happens if you remove `RewriteBase /HR/`and also remove the forward slash in front of all instances of `index.php`?

Comment: @DevinYoung yes I did delete it..

Comment: @Mudshark it won't work..

Comment: @DevinYoung - Please check the error I'm getting after allowing the override for all.. as I read It should be always enabled. otherwise it'll ignore the `.htaccess`

Comment: @Mudshark - Please check the error I'm getting after allowing the override for all.. as I read It should be always enabled. otherwise it'll ignore the `.htaccess`

Comment: New thought--where is the location of the .htaccess file? In which directory?

Comment: @DevinYoung - this is the path: `Apache24\htdocs\HR\.htaccess`

Comment: Are you positive that your mod_rewrite is "mod_rewrite.c" and not "mod_rewrite.so"? Try changing to "mod_rewrite.so" and see if you have better luck.

Comment: @DevinYoung - thank you. I already used the answer you provided and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to completely change your  .htaccess entirely, but here is an example of the one I use that I never have any issues with. This is only the part in regards to modrewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(templates|plugins)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Okay, that's it... Thank you. I just had to edit the rewritebase and add the /HR for it... thanks again.